# Calling window.onload = init; in text/babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my html page I do some ReactJS and I have `<script type="text/babel" src="resources/js/main.jsx"></script>` and there I have following code, and it doesn't work. "Search" here is a JSX function.

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById('search');
  button.onclick = search;
}

function search() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Tabs />,
    document.getElementById('tabstarget')
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Body />,
    document.getElementById('body')
  );
};
```

`

if I isolate this code in separate JS file, and have separate JSX file with the "search" function like:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="resources/js/main.jsx"></script>
<script src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
```

then my button doesn't see search function as it is in another scope, because Babel appends "use strict" to compiled results.

The only way then is to manually precompile JSX file to JS and append it to main.js. Then it works fine. It is not convenient as I need to do that every time I want to try my changes in JSX.
What am I doing wrong and how to call JSX function without manually precompiling it each time? Thank you.